# How can I add memberof attribute to ldap user via phpldapadmin

Tags: ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

I am using openldap to create a simple user and simple group.

```
dn: cn=User2 Engineer,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
cn: User2 Engineer
gidnumber: 501
givenname: User2
homedirectory: /home/users/u2engineer
loginshell: /bin/sh
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: top
sn: Engineer
uid: u2engineer
uidnumber: 1002
userpassword: {MD5}xxxxxxx


# Entry 1: cn=network engineers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=net
dn: cn=network engineers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=net
cn: network engineers
gidnumber: 501
memberuid: user1ene
memberuid: u2engineer
objectclass: posixGroup
objectclass: top
```

I would like to relate the user to the group by adding memberof attribute to user entry.
it mean i need to add groupOfNames objectclass to user, groupOfNames is in core.schema
but it can add that objectclass to user neither via phpldapadmin nor ldapmodify.
i got error:

```
LDAP said:  Object class violation
Error number:   0x41 (LDAP_OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION)
```

I am sure that core.schema has been imported to openldap successfully.

What is the possible cause?
How can I add memberof attribute to users?

Thanks!

> -SG-

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The `memberOf` attribute is an operational attribute maintained automatically by the `memberof` overlay. You can't set it yourself.

Adding the `groupOfNames` object class to the user entry doesn't make sense either. That object class is for, err, groups of names, such as roles, and it has a `member` attribute to which you add the DN of the user. Then the `memberOf` attribute of the user is automatically updated to include the DN of the group.

You're doing this all back to front.